# What are the benefits of Akka extensions?

Tags: java, akka

I'm very new to Akka and trying to understand how to deal with dependency injection. I came across this [examle](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-akka-java-spring), which lead me to Akka extensions and now I'm trying to understand how is it differ from simple static method invocation. Akka tutorials section about extensions has something like this as example:

```
public class CountExtensionImpl implements Extension {

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

    public long increment() {
        return counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}

public class CountExtension extends AbstractExtensionId<CountExtensionImpl> implements ExtensionIdProvider {

    public static final CountExtension EXTENSION = new CountExtension();

    private CountExtension() {

    }

    @Override
    public CountExtensionImpl createExtension(ExtendedActorSystem system) {
        return new CountExtensionImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionId<? extends Extension> lookup() {
        return EXTENSION;
    }
}

public class MyActor extends UntypedActor{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(CountExtension.EXTENSION.get(getContext().system()).increment());

    }
}
```

But I can't understand what are the advantages over simple singleton or static method? E.g.

```
public class MyActor extends UntypedActor{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        Counter.increment();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Akka Extension gets bound to to an ActorSystem and as such is a singleton-per-system rather than a global singleton.

Comment: Agree, but it is still a singleton, which looks like an Anti-Pattern to me. What's the benefit of extensions vs dependency injection/event-publish bus for example? Would you rather use extensions for cross-concern or database connection management? Sorry if my question sounds silly, I may not have fully grasped Akka-Extension's concept.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that it's designed to be used for "zookeeping" purposes? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Index